# How to convert xls to xlsx in vb.net?

Tags: devexpress, vb.net-2010

I am using a resource file(abc.xls) in my project.

" IO.File.WriteAllBytes(tempPath, My.Resources.abc) "

But i want to use abc.xlsx instead of abc.xls without changing resourse file.

can I do saveAs? how?
or please give any other solution.

Thanks.......

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you exactly want to do, but I'll try to answer the second portion of your question.

```
 'Make a path where you want to save the file

Dim Path as String
Path = "C:\Programs\blabla\"

Dim Final As String
Final = Path & "Filename.xlsx"

YourWorkBook.SaveAs(Final)
```

Or just try searching google for a more detailed explanation. (You've given little no none info, showing very little research made)
Try searching "How to save excel file in vb.net"